# what kind of matrix is this?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, terminology

Suppose I generate a matrix using this pattern:

```
A = zeros
k = 1
for i = 1 to n:
  for j = i+1 to n:
     A[k, i] = A[k, j] = 1
     k += 1
```

Here's an example of $A_4$:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}

This pattern has shown up in my combinatorial optimization problems. Does it have a name? Are any properties known for this form of matrix? It has two set bits in each row and $n-1$ set bits in each column.

Comment: I would name it, "A matrix whose rows are the two-element subsets of the set {1, 2, 3, 4}, encoded as zero-one vectors, in reverse-lexicographic order."